# If a flying dragon drops you 100ft, can you use misty step to avoid the fall damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, falling

So to clarify I know in Xanathars fall damage happens immediately, but does it happen on your turn or in this case the dragons turn when it drops you? And to follow up could a player use misty step right before they hit the ground to mitigate the damage?

Comment: *immediately* :-)